# Operator not applicable to this operand type+Socks+SSL

Tags: delphi, proxy, delphi-xe

Trying some proxy stuff, i get this error : `Operator not applicable to this operand type` , i used visual component before and it was good, now i changed the code i get this..code below.

```
  var 
    lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    Socks : TIdSocksInfo;
    Host, Port : String;
  begin
    try
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);


      lHTTp.ReadTimeout := 60000;

      IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];

      IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      IdSSL.TransparentProxy := Socks.Create(lHTTP);

      (IdSSL.TransparentProxy as Socks).Port := Port.ToInteger(); //Error
      (IdSSL.TransparentProxy as Socks).Host := Host;            //Error

      (IdSSL.TransparentProxy as Socks).Version := svSocks5;  //Error

      lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
      lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

   end;
```

Comment: i see.., post it as answer, thank you @Victoria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typecasts are wrong, that is why you are getting errors. You need to cast to a type, not to a variable name:

```
(IdSSL.TransparentProxy as TIdSocksInfo).Port := Port.ToInteger;
(IdSSL.TransparentProxy as TIdSocksInfo).Host := Host;
(IdSSL.TransparentProxy as TIdSocksInfo).Version := svSocks5;
```

A better option is to use the variable you have declared, and don't use typecasts at all:

```
Socks := Socks.Create(lHTTP);
Socks.Port := Port.ToInteger;
Socks.Host := Host;
Socks.Version := svSocks5;
IdSSL.TransparentProxy := Socks;
```